# Why won't slice work?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm trying to write a chrome extension.

For the extension, if users input a string, I want the first two characters to be sliced off.

Currently, I have:

```
if (text.charAt(0) == '/') {
    text.slice(0,2);
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "PrivateURL" + text
    });
}
```

But it's not working, nothing is being sliced off. I have a feeling something is wrong with my syntax, as I'm still learning. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: slice returns a copy of the array, it doesn't change the var it's called on

Comment: The same applies to [`Array.prototype.slice`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Slice does not work "in place" but returns the value:

```
var text = "Hello World";
console.log(text.slice(0,2));
// He
console.log(text);
// Hello World    (unchanged!)
```

You need to assign it to the variable like this:

```
text = text.slice(0,2);
```

Also, from your question, it sounds as if you're trying to remove the first two letters. That would be

```
var text = "Hello World";
text = text.slice(2);
// will be "llo World"
```

Comment: Cheers! That is what I wanted, but I must have misread http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp as I understood the first value to be 'Start' (Where the slice starts) and the second value to be 'End', and that I should speciffy a start of '0' and an end of '2'. I now understand that when beginning from the start of the string, I can just specify an 'End' point so to speak.

Comment: i'm glad i could help. StackOverflow lets you mark an answer as "accepted" - this way others know that it's answered, and as a side-effect i also get a few extra points ;-)

Comment: Yes! No problem. I intended to do so, but as I'm new, Stack Overflow makes me wait an obnoxious amount of time before doing these things.

Answer (score 6):

Strings are Immutable, you cannot modify a string, but you can do some operations on the string and return a new string

so `slice()` does not actually modify value in text, to make it work you should put

```
text = text.slice(0,2);
```